# Django - How to create checkbox form separated by foreign key

Tags: django

I'm developing food site, where users can register favorite foods to this web site. So, I would like to create checkbox form separated by foreign key like this.

Fruits
□ Apple
☑︎ Orange
☑︎ Lemon

Vegetable
□ Tomato
☑︎ Eggplant
☑︎ Cucumber

---

Table
● FoodsType
id | name
1, Fruits
2, Vegetable

● Foods
id | name | type_id
1, Apple, 1
2, Orange, 1
3, Lemon, 1
4, Tomato, 2
5, Eggplant, 2
6, Cucumber, 2

● UserFoods
id | foods_id | user_id
1,  2, 1
2, 3, 1
3,  5, 1
4, 6, 1
5,  2, 2
6, 3, 2
7,  5, 2
8, 2, 3

Here is my code:

▪️ models.py

```
class FoodsType(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Foods(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    type = models.ForeignKey(FoodsType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class UserFoods(models.Model):
    foods = models.ManyToManyField(Foods)
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

▪️ form.py

```
class FoodsFrom(forms.ModelForm):
    foods = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(label='favorite foods', queryset=Foods.objects.all(), widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)

    class Meta:
        model = Foods
        fields = ('name', 'type')
```

▪️ view.py

```
class registerForm(generic.CreateView):

    def get(self, request):
        food_form = FoodsFrom()
        context = {
            'food_form': food_form
        }
        return render(request, 'register.html', context)
```

▪️ register.html

```
{% for field in food_form %}
    <tr>
        <th><label for="{{ field.id_for_label }}">{{ field.label }}</label></th>
        <td>{{ field }} {{ field.errors }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

current result
□ Apple
☑︎ Orange
☑︎ Lemon
□ Tomato
☑︎ Eggplant
☑︎ Cucumber

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the built-in template regroup : https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup

For your exemple it should looks like this:

```
{% regroup food_form.foods by food_form.type as foods_list %}

    <ul>
{% for type in foods_list %}
    <li>{{ type.grouper }}
    <ul>
        {% for food in type.list %}
          <li>{{ food.foods }}: {{ food.name }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: Resolved by this site. But, Thank you for your help!
https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/10573/